# Substituting for a malloc

Tags: c

Given the following function `to_lower`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void to_lower(char ** strings) {
    char * original_string, lower_string;
    for (int i=0; (original_string=strings[i]) != NULL; i++) {
        lower_string = malloc(strlen(original_string)+1);
        for (int j=0; j<=strlen(original_string); j++) 
            lower_string[j] = tolower(original_string[j]);
        strings[i]=lower_string;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char * strings[] = {"Hello", "Zerotom", "new", NULL };
    to_lower(strings);
}
```

Would it be possible to do the same function without calling `malloc`? If so, how would that be done? I am trying to see if I can change the "value of" the pointer in place without having to allocate new memory for it.

Comment: `strlen(original_string + 1)` is incorrect. It should be `(strlen(original_string) + 1)`

Comment: The simple answer is "no."  Overwriting the literal strings would invoke undefined behavior, so fresh memory must be allocated. Of course if the input array of pointers pointed to `malloc`ed memory, then this routine leaks. So the bigger answer is that the semantics of the function are fragile. It's better practice to refrain from mutating the input at all. Allocate _both_ a fresh array of pointers and new strings and return that with the contract that the caller is responsible for freeing the whole shebang.

Comment: @Gene -- thanks for that input. Could you please show how that would be done in practice?

Comment: @Shared You pass the function a bunch of pointers to string constants. By definition, constants can't be modified. If you want the function to modify the thing the pointers point to, the pointers can't point to constants.

Comment: You could work with a variant on `char strings[][20] = { "Hello", "Zerotom", "new", "" };` but you couldn't use a null pointer to mark the end — I've used an empty string, but you could simply give a count instead of using a sentinel (null pointer or empty string).

Comment: Your declaration of `char * original_string, lower_string;` declares a single character `lower_string`, not a pointer. Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the max, for GCC this is at least `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @Shared Do you mean that you want to change the case ("value") of the *strings* in place? I.e., convert the data to lower-case in the `strings` array in function `main()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your two issues are that you are intending to change constant string literals and that your function's behaviour relies on the properties of your data structure (i.e. properly terminated strings and a NULL pointer as the last element).

So I suggest to setup a fixed-size data structure at startup time, then to set and change the contents, and to finally cleanup everything again - like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 10
#define NUM 3

char **init (int num, int len) {
    char **strings = calloc(num, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        strings[i] = calloc(len, sizeof(char));
    }
    return strings;
}

void teardown (char **strings, int num) {
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        free(strings[i]);
    }
    free(strings);
}

void to_lower(char **strings, int num, int len) {
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < len; j++) 
            strings[i][j] = tolower(strings[i][j]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // startup
    char **strings = init(NUM, LEN);

    // do things
    sprintf(strings[0], "%s", "Hello");
    sprintf(strings[1], "%s", "Zerotom");
    sprintf(strings[2], "%s", "new");
    to_lower(strings, NUM, LEN);

    // shutdown
    teardown(strings, NUM);
    return 0;
}
```